# FTP username with | (pipe) in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

I'm trying to FTP files to a remote location. But here is the issue I'm facing.

When I use the below script, I'm able to login to the remote server but I'm not able to place any files over there, 550 access denied log prompt.

```
echo user domain/username> ftp.txt
echo password>> ftp.txt
echo cd remotepath>> ftp.txt
echo put FTPTest.txt>>ftp.txt
echo quit>> ftp.txt

ftp -n -s ftp.txt Servername>ftp_logs.txt

del ftp.txt
```

I tried to login via command prompt. I successfully Ftp'd, if the username is like `Servername|domain/username`.

I modified the script as below, script is not even executing.

```
echo user Servername|domain/username> ftp.txt
echo password>> ftp.txt
echo cd remotepath>> ftp.txt
echo put FTPTest.txt>>ftp.txt
echo quit>> ftp.txt

ftp -n -s ftp.txt Servername>ftp_logs.txt

del ftp.txt
```

Searching for clues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `|`, as that has a special meaning in Windows:

```
echo user Servername^|domain/username> ftp.txt
```

The above will get you

```
user Servername|domain/username
```

in the `ftp.exe`.